# Song files for public performance

Tags: licensing, music

Once I've paid a Performing Rights Organization (eg. ASCAP) for a public performance license, how do I obtain the actual music files? Do the licensing companies provide them, or do I need to purchase them from a music retailer? Can I use a streaming service like Spotify? The FAQs on the licensing sites are unclear about this.

Comment: When you want to use a sound recording under a license, wouldn't you typically already have a copy of the recording, so you know what you're getting?

Comment: Not in this situation, no. I need access to a whole bunch of songs for a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make contact the organization you have in mind, but in general the license only expands the rights you already have when you acquire a work of music.

Comment: "The rights you already have" would (in the USA) include the right to perform the works in public, provided the performance meets the criteria of a statutory exemption (e.g., not for commercial advantage and where nobody is making a profit, under 17USC 110(4)).